# Unable to scroll screen in Windows Phone 8 phonegap Application

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am facing a problem in scrolling few pages in Windows Phone 8 application. The application is built in phonegap. It is working fine in android and iOS. The page does not scroll to the bottom , thus I don't view the whole screen. Earlier I was facing a problem where a full List was not visible and some portion of bottom screen was cut. To resolve it , I made the following changes in config.xml -

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0xffffffff" />
```

This helped me resolving my earlier problem but now I am not able to scroll the screen to see the full page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Same is happening with me. Did you got any workaround?